# Game of Rock Paper Scissors does not work as expected

Tags: python

I was trying to make something quick and easy, the game known as Rock Paper Scissors, because I'm just learning. I got it to work using Python shell but when I re-typed the code in a websites code tester, it kept saying `EOFError` and it was saying the problem was in line 3 of the `if` statement

Here is my code:

```py
import random

foe = random.randint(1, 3)
you = int(input("pick 1-3"))
print(you)
if you == foe:
    print("it's a tie")
elif you > foe:
    try:
        print("checking for special conditions")
    except:
        if you == 3 and foe == 1:
            print("you lose")
    else:
        print("you win")
    finally:
        print("complete")
else:
    try:
        print("checking for special conditions")
    except:
        if you == 1 and foe == 3:
            print("you win")
    else:
        print("you lose")
    finally:
        print("complete")
```

All of this code worked in shell I don't understand what it is that made it incorrect.

Quick side note: I'm 13 years old and I got into coding by a video I saw made by code-bullet.

I went here and saw people with the same problem and I looked at the solutions thinking it would fix it, but all it did was bring up another error I did end up deleting that line of code and I have no idea what is wrong with the `if` statement

Comment: (1) Please do not post code as image. Instead you could type the code. (2) The last image shows code that has invalid code at the very end, as there is nothing following the colon of that `except`; and it also doesn't match with a `try`. (3) W3schools is not really the place to run code reliably. Maybe install PyCharm on your PC?

Comment: You may want to check [ask]

Comment: i'm using a Chromebook from my school to learn and create code, and since it's from my school I have restrictions on what i can download. i even had to do a work around their restrictions to create an account and ask this question, and i just started today so i rushed to ask this question and i didn't look at the guidelines needed to post. i apologize for any trouble I may have caused you and i will go back and change my post to a certain requirement you requested, just as long as this post gets reopened so I can get some answers that i need. i was asking this because i'm making this for dad.

Comment: Using more than one space of indentation will make your code more readable. BTW, the style guide for Python suggests [four spaces of indentation](https://pep8.org/#indentation), you should go with that.

Comment: I ended up going with the four spaces on the first edit right off the bat because it said it detected code and it needed four spaces, it didn't even say anything about single indentations and with

Comment: Slow down there. *Stack Overflow* needs four spaces for code sections (or triple backticks). They're there, it's fine. And - completely unrelated - there's *Python* which wants you to put more indentation in the lines after e.g. an `if`. You use one space, should be four each. That's not your original problem, though. Just a guide you should follow. You can safely ignore that for now.

Comment: As to your code, I think you just forgot to close a parenthesis in `you=int(input("pick 1-3")`. You see, you open two parens, but just close one. Change it to `you=int(input("pick 1-3"))` and your program will run.

Comment: for the line you=int(input("pick 1-3") i did put double parenthesis in the original but i guess i forgot to put it in here

Comment: True, there's two closing parentheses in the images you posted earlier. I can only confirm your program runs after I added the parenthesis. I cannot reproduce your error. I don't see how the errors you get should be related to your code. Trincot suggested that w3schools does not run code reliably so it may be an error on their end.

Comment: Why do you have a print wrapped in a try? Do you expect it to raise an exception?

Comment: I have that print there as a placeholder because earlier before I made this post, I am new to any code (python is no exception) and I found it always activates the command wrapped in the try portion with the command either in the except portion or the else portion and always the finally. i used the try print and the finally print just in case the code worked a little slow, so it would print "checking for special conditions" at the start of it and "complete" at the end

Comment: You don't need the `try` blocks. Assuming the program you are writing is stone-scissors-paper, you would need to remove the lines with `try`, `except` and `finally` and *unindent* the line with `if you == 3 and foe == 1: ` so it aligns with the `else` below. You want to have `if ... else` at the same level, not `try ... else`.

Comment: i will go back and see if that changes anything in shell, also yes i was trying to make rock paper scissors since i'm a beginning coder trying to make something quick and easy, yet it turned into something long and difficult

Comment: As your code is written, you can never lose with a 3 because the lines below `except` will never be executed. Removing the `try`, `except` and `finally` stuff will enable you to lose with a 3 if your foe picks a 1. For debugging, you can `print(foe)` to see what they're up to. Debugging is fun ...

Comment: i was kinda going for how it is in real life where you don't know what they chose until they threw it, it makes it a little suspenseful and they get surprised when they realized they either lost or won. i just looked over my code and i don't see why you can't lose, if they had 2 and you had 1 it would go down the path where you have less than them, then it checks if they had 3 (which in this case they don't) and if not it activates the else function in that path.

Comment: also before now i was only able to use python shell, then i looked in the chrome web store under the tab of apps and extensions my school allows and i found an actual coding extension where you can choose to run instead of it running in the code

Comment: is there anything else I need to change to at least have a chance to have this opened back up

Comment: It's a community decision whether this question will be re-opened so I can't really tell. I tried to make the question's title more meaningful. SO isn't exactly the most friendly place for new users. At the same time, we do see a lot of bad questions.

Answer (score 0):

Find your code with some improvements below (a nice community member already formatted the code in the question). I can confirm it works on my machine with Python 3.11. I cannot tell you whether it will run on some online code evaluation site. I see no reason why it shouldn't but you would need to try.

I took the liberty to sanitize the input to make sure it's always between 1 and 3, inclusive. Otherwise, it would be too easy to cheat by entering a number greater than 3.

Furthermore, I removed all the superfluous `try..except..else..finally` statements. It does not speed up your code or act as a failsafe. It's just faulty logic. What you want in this case is just `if..else`. The difference is as follows:

```
try:
    # a statement that may raise an exception to signal an error
    # no, print() is not one of them
except:
    # catch the exception and do something to mitigate the error
else:
    # do something if no exception occurred, i.e. there was no error
finally:
    # do something regardless of whether there was an error or not
```

And even in "serious" programs, we rarely need all of these.

In your original code, that would mean:

```
try:
    print("checking for special conditions")
    # no exception, let's skip the "except" block
except:
    # we never get here because there was no exception
    # the code below is never executed
    if you == 3 and foe == 1:
        print("you lose")
else:
    # always jump here, we always win, huzzah!
    print("you win")
finally:
    # jump here and print "complete"
    print("complete")
```

What you mean to do instead is to use a simple conditional expression to do something `if` the condition is met or `else` something else.

```
import random

foe = random.randint(1, 3)
you = int(input("pick 1-3 "))

# make sure the input is between 1 and 3
if you < 1:
    you = 1
elif you > 3:
    you = 3

print(you)
if you == foe:
    print("it's a tie")
elif you > foe:
    print("checking for special conditions")
    if you == 3 and foe == 1:
        print("you lose")
    else:
        print("you win")
else:
    print("checking for special conditions")
    if you == 1 and foe == 3:
        print("you win")
    else:
        print("you lose")

print("complete")
```

There would be more you could improve in your program. You can play with it and see how things change.